# Joomla component upload error 500

Tags: php, cms, joomla, http-code-500

When I try to upload a Joomla component via the the Joomla extension upload manager I receive a error 500 message. What can be the cause of the problem? How do i fix it?

Note: I have tried changing the folder permissions to 777 but the error persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under Help > System Info > Directory Permissions, make sure all the folders listed are writeable, particulaly the `tmp` and `components` folders.

On the "PHP Information" tab, make sure it lists some form of ZIP support appropriate to the file you're upload (e.g. 'zip' or 'gzip').

The most common reason for 500 errors though is a misconfigured `.htaccess` file. Are you using anything in addition to the standard Joomla one?